# How to force download instead of opening srt file in Chrome from an FTP server using Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, download, srt

I have to download srt file from an FTP server and I'm using this code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").bind('click', function () {
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = 'ftp://192.168.1.1/mytextfile.srt';
            a.download = 'mytextfile.srt';
            a.click();
        });
    });
</script>
<html>
    <a>Download</a>
</html>
```

The problem is that the file in Chrome is opened and *not* downloaded. I want when the user click on the download link to download srt file. How can I force Chrome to download the file?

I need to do this in javascript/jQuery not php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot manipulate HTTP headers from an FTP server, FTP only provides data. Therefore you cannot use the `download` attribute nor the `Content-Disposition` header.

This means it is up to the Chrome browser to decide how to deal with the file severed through FTP. I suggest you serve your files from an HTTP server instead of using FTP.

Afterwards, you can either set the [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header in the response as an `attachment` on the server-side:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.srt"
```

or use HTML5 anchor's [`download` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes), but be aware:

> - Although HTTP(s) **URLs need to be in the same-origin**, blob: URLs and data are allowed so that content generated by JavaScript can be downloaded.
> - If the HTTP header Content-Disposition: gives a different filename than this attribute, the HTTP header takes priority over this attribute.
> - If Content-Disposition: is set to inline, Firefox prioritizes Content-Disposition, like the filename case, while Chrome prioritizes the download attribute.

Comment: I have http://192.168.1.1 where my web page is accessed and when user click on that page download button it needs to download from ftp://192.168.1.1 so the ip is the sam, domain is the same only difference is the http and ftp..so how to download srt text file while http and ftp is in game?

Comment: @IgorPetev Unfortunately, I can't think of a standard way of doing this on the client-side using JavaScript.

Comment: Ok...i will try to add it to server side using php